# Execute after close dialog

Tags: java, android, class

I have a button that open a dialog for change a number. The button is in activity, and generate a new class names dialogs, for storage different dialogs.

**Dialog consigna:** Dialogs.class

```
public String consigna(){


        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctxt);
        alert.setTitle("Nueva temperatura");
        alert.setMessage("Agrega una nueva temperatura");
        final EditText input = new EditText(ctxt);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        input.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        alert.setView(input);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
               data = input.getText().toString();

            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                //Put actions for CANCEL button here, or leave in blank
            }
        });
        alert.show();

     return data;
    }
```

**on click button:** MainActivity

```
//I need change these two values:

final public double temperatura = 200.3;
String newData;

...

public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.tempConsigna:
               dialog = new Dialogs(MainActivity.this);
               String data = dialog.consigna();
               newData = data;
                break;

...//other cases...
```

The issue is in newData = data; I doesn't have a data, because the dialog not are closed. The dialog work in other thread,no?

How to change newData var with the dialog result? It is posible into a dialogs class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a callback method implemented via an interface:

```
      public String consigna(final OnConfirm confirm){
            final String[] data = new String[1];
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            alert.setTitle("Nueva temperatura");
            alert.setMessage("Agrega una nueva temperatura");
            final EditText input = new EditText(activity);
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            input.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            alert.setView(input);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                     data[0] = input.getText().toString();
                    confirm.onConfirm(data[0]);
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    //Put actions for CANCEL button here, or leave in blank
                }
            });
            alert.show();

            return data[0];
        }


 public interface OnConfirm {
         void onConfirm(String s);
    }
```

And in your Main Activity

```
Dialogs dialog = new Dialogs(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.consigna(new Dialogs.OnConfirm() {
            @Override
            public void onConfirm(String s) {

                Log.d("data", s);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not return result as you want but after click on dialog ok button then access data variable. no need to return.

Comment: Yes, I know. But how to change a variable in main activity with the results of dialog??

Comment: can you share code of activity apart from that you shared?

Comment: consigna(); simple call this method and no need to do these things you have done.

Comment: When I click a button, he execute a consigna method, and inmediatelly after, the newData=data. In this moment data is empty. I need Fill this bar, after the dialog are closed. Or take newData var into a click callback on dialog. But, if I pass a String ,all good, but I cant pass a double dor example.

Comment: You have to work on ok positive button listener that you want to do.